# jQuery post to servlet and refreshing parent page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

This is what I am trying to do, based on the ajax jQuery documents I am reading. I want to send a post call to a servlet I wrote, which will save an entry in my database. After that post is successful, I want to reload the PARENT of the iFrame that renders my initial page.

So what I currently have correctly makes the post call, but I have no parameters outside of the callback parameter.

So I have a couple questions:

- Am I doing the post correctly? Do I actually need to post the parameter list as a jsonp string?
- How would I correctly send a "succeed" call from the servlet AFTER I submit to the DB?

Servlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        System.out.println(request.getQueryString());
    }
}
```

Result from my servlet:

```
callback=jQuery183010119481382259055_1374511172363
```

View call (jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
function funcCallBack() {
    var param12 = $('input:radio[name=param1]:checked').val();
    var param22 = $('[name="param2"]').val();
    var param32 = $('[name="param3"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {param1:param12, param2:param22, param3:param32},
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/App/url',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        beforeSend:function(){$('#replace').empty().append('&lt;div style="width:54px;height:55px;position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;margin:-27.5px 0 0 -27px;"&gt;&lt;img src="/App/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading Results"/&gt;&lt;/div&gt;');}
    }).done(function() { alert('success'); });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I doing the post correctly? Do I actually need to post the
>   parameter list as a jsonp string?

Yes, you are doing it correctly. And you dont need to pass the parameter list as `jsonp`. Correct type for data is `PlainObject` or `String`.
`datatype` indicates the type of data that you're expecting back from the server and not the type of data you are sending.

> How would I correctly send a "succeed" call from the servlet AFTER I
>   submit to the DB?

No, You dont need to explicitly indicate a successful return. `success` function is invoked when the request succeeds.

Comment: OK - So I added a .done call on the end of the ajax call (similar to what I am seeing on their docs), but the call never happens. I'll update my question with that code

Comment: Actually - If I make that a .fail, it's called. So it's failing.

Comment: You're right about JSONP - That was causing the failure. Thanks!